# Jmeter Samples count request different with same setting

Tags: concurrency, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

helo, im so new on jmeter

and confused how the samples of summary report count, cz im using plug-in bzm - Concurrency Thread Group.. with the same setting of target concurrency, ramp up time, ramp-up step count, and hold target rate time can give different count of samples, how can i count the samples correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by "correctly"?

If you use [Concurrency Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/) you cannot precisely control the number of sample results because **it mainly depends on your application response time**, lower response time - more sample results, higher response time - less sample results.

If you're looking for a way of making strictly X requests - add [Throughput Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller) and specify how many requests you want to make:

[image]

More information: [Advanced Load Testing Scenarios with JMeter Part 4 - Stepping Thread Group and Concurrency Thread Group](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-load-testing-scenarios-jmeter-part-4-stepping-thread-group-and-concurrency-thread)

Comment: ah i see, i just get confused since the result not always have same samples on summary report whenever i run the test.

thanks for your help! im gonna try Throughput Controller first!